# Is there some way to run PyDev alone as a LSP server?

Tags: pydev

As it is said in https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/servers ,   PyDev is a LSP server for Python. So how to run it as a LSP server ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using https://www.pydev.org/vscode/index.html (still note that although PyDev itself is free/open source, this particular integration to use it as a language server is commercial).